# Use old iPod touch screen

Tags: ipod, screen

So I have a cracked ipod touch 4 Gen screen. Is there any use for this now? Is there possibly a way to get an adapter to HDMI or something similar? The screen works fine besides the cracked glass.

Comment: You can also sell it on eBay, but people would probably on;y pay 40-50 bucks

Answer (score 2):

Apple (Wal-mart, Best buy, and others carry it also) does sell 30 pin to HDMI. If you have an Apple TV you could stream via Airplay.

If you are adventurous you could try to replace the screen and digitizer, I did a [quick search on Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_20?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=ipod%20touch%204th%20gen%20digitizer&sprefix=ipod%20touch%204th%20gen%20d,aps,287) and came up with multiple prices above and below twenty dollars. For directions search Youtube or iFixit.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can sell it to [Gazelle](http://Gazelle.com) for some cash.
2. You could buy a replacement screen on [iFixit](http://iFixit.com) and replace it yourself.
3. I have seen many people with severely cracked screens just live with it.